# Can I use Visual Studio Team Services as a build server only?

Tags: tfs, build, azure-devops

I am considering how practical it would be for our company to utilize Visual Studio Team Services as our build controller.

We currently utilize SVN as our repository, and JIRA as our change control / bug reporting agent. We have no real desire to change this process at this time.

Everything I have seen so far works on the premise that Team Services is utilized as the source control and change control agent. I realize that I can utilize a SVN task in MSBuild, but can I integrate this somehow into a trigger for a build?

Is it possible to use Team Services just as the CI build controller?

Comment: Guessing you have but let me just ask if you have considered using Bamboo as your build agent?

Comment: I have not. We currently use CCNET. We maintain MSDN licenses for all our developers so we also have access to TFS. Bamboo it appears would incur additional charges per build agent.

Comment: You "could", the question is really, "should you?", and that's too broad a topic for a site like stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this aspect Team Services is all or nothing. It's an integrated solution and Source Control is at the heart of that.

Team Services has 2 types of Source Control. A centralized repository which is very similar to SVN, and as of TFS 2013 you can also host a Git repository within Team Services.

If you want to use Team Services as a build engine then you need to migrate your source in to one of these kinds of repository.

I would say that if you're already using SVN and Jira, and you're happy with that, then there is very little reason to migrate to Team Services. Something like Team City, Jenkins or CCNet is your best bet.

Comment: Thank you. That was the general feeling I was getting but wanted to confirm the 'one ring to rule them all' schema for TFS. :)

Comment: A note for people looking for up to date info
You can use an external git repo and ignore the provided one and run it as a build server
You still get all the other VSTS stuff but you don't have to use it
I am able to get code from bitbucket, build in VSTS, and push to AWS; all within VSTS

Comment: @Arch yep the world has changed quite a lot in the last 2 years. Both VSTS and TFS support external Git repos now

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a trigger.  An alternative to try, which may seem like over kill.  Create an empty project in Team Services, setup a tool like [SvnTFSSync](http://ficusdev.com/SvnTfsSync/Configuration), and essentially sync your SVN to Team Services checkins.  Once you do that, you can setup Team Services checkin triggers to automate the build.

Like James Reed said, with Team Services in this case, its all or nothing really.